# What is the largest buffer size for ioctl?

Tags: rhel, ioctl

I am using `ioctl()` to read data from a block device (scsi.)

I have noticed that when I read `1024` sectors, `ioctl` finishes without a problem. When I read `2048`, after a few long moments it returns `ENOMEM` (`errno=12`) which is not even listed on the list of possible errors (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html)

I have tripple checked that I am passing proper buffer size, so this cannot be the case - no buffer overrun.

How can I learn the largest buffer size to be read using `ioctl` then?

#### Edit 1

Some additional information may become helpful:

```
Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Carthage)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)
2.6.18-128.el5
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs as the default behaviour of Linux memory management, which is "overcommiting". This means that the kernel claims to allocate memory successfuly, but doesn't actually allocate the memory until later when you try to access it. If the kernel finds out that it's allocated too much memory, it kills a process with "the ENOMEM (Out Of Memory) killer" to free up some memory. The way it picks the process to kill is complicated, but if you have just allocated most of the memory in the system, it's probably going to be your process that gets the bullet.

To change this behaviour try the following :

```
echo "2" > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

On Linux 2.6 and later, it is possible to modify the kernel's behavior so that it will not "overcommit" memory. Although this setting will not prevent the OOM killer from being invoked altogether, it will lower the chances significantly and will therefore lead to more robust system behavior. This is done by selecting strict overcommit mode via sysctl:

```
sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

Comment: It is interesting that `ioctl` returns ENOMEM after few long moments.... After writing 2 into `overcommit_memory` nothing changed - the very same behavior. No `/var/log/messages` or `dmesg` events also. Is `overcommit_memory` read-write? When I `cat` from it, it still shows `0` to me. It is 5.3 Linux. 2.6.18-128.el5. (I will update my original post with this data.)

Comment: proc/sys/ might be mounted readonly, try http://serverfault.com/questions/82728/overcommitting-memory-on-an-ubuntu-server-9-10-running-on-vmware-fusion-3-0-osx

Comment: Kind of strange. `cat /proc/mount` shows me all being mounted as `rw`, and I am `root`. Nonetheless, after rebooting, and echoing 2 to `overcommit_memory`, now it shows '2' when I `cat` from it. Anyway, after the change I still have the same behavior. I also allocated memory using `mmap` with the `MAP_LOCKED` flag, and still nothing. Note that my machine has 96GB memory. I really have aaaalot of it. Thank you for your valuable time!